# Is this not downcasting?

Tags: c++, conventions, downcast

If I do

```
double d = 34.56;
int i = (int)d;
```

Am I not "downcasting"?

OR

Is this term only used in terms of classes and objects?

---

I am confused because in this case we are "downcasting" from a bigger `double` to a smaller `int`, but in case of classes, we "downcast" from a smaller `base class` to a bigger `derived class`.

Aren't these two conventions, in some sense, opposite?

Comment: You don't need the cast, as `int i = d;` will do the same thing, so there's no real association with casting.

Comment: @David Thornley: I only get a warning! I was expecting an error (knowing that C++ is more strongly typed than C++)...

Comment: No, it's allowed (see section 4.9 of the Standard), although if the value is out of range the results are undefined.  In this case, since an `int` has to be able to represent the value 34, that's what it is (and has to be according to the Standard).  The warning is completely up to the compiler writers, although such truncation warnings are common.  While C++ tries to be more strongly typed than C, it can't always succeed.  Banning "Floating-integral conversions" would cause too much existing C code to be incompatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not down casting.  You are just casting, and you're chopping off anything after the decimal.

Down casting doesn't apply here.  The primitives `int` and `double` are not objects in C++ and are not related to each other in the way two objects in a class hierarchy are.  They are separate and primitive entities.

Down casting refers to the act of casting one object into another object that derives from it. It refers to the act of moving down from the root of the class hierarchy.  It has nothing to do with the sizes of types in question.

Comment: it is not floor. floor converts to smaller int. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/ for negative it will be -2.5 -> -3.0

Comment: Removed the reference to floor.  Best not to over complicate anyway ;)

Comment: @John: it is a cast. It is, of course, also a conversion. 5.4.

Comment: @John It is a cast and a conversion.  As Steve pointed out.  It's still type casting, even though it results in the conversion of the value contained.

Answer (score 7):

> Downcasting is the act of casting a
>   reference of a base class to one of
>   its derived classes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting

No, you do not downcast, since double and int are not classes.

Comment: And since he's not converting a reference, but a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `double` are both primitives and not classes, so the concepts of classes don't apply to them.

Yes, it is a conversion from a "larger" to a "smaller" type (in terms of numerical size), but it's just a "cast" and not a "downcast"

Answer (score 0):

The two aren't so much opposite as simply unrelated. In the example case, we're taking a value of one type, and the cast takes that and produces a similar value of a type that's vaguely similar, but completely unrelated.

In the case of traversing an inheritance tree with something like `dynamic_cast`, we're taking a pointer (or reference) to an object, and having previously decided to treat it as a pointer to some other type of object, we're basically (attempting to) treat it as (something closer to) the original type of object again. In particular, however, we're *not* creating a new or different value at all -- we're simply creating a different view of the same value (i.e., the same actual object).

Answer (score -1):

You aren't casting -- you're converting.  Different thing entirely.

Comment: -1. He's converting by means of a cast. What's in question is whether it's a "downcast" or not (I don't think C++ defines the term).